# Can't find 'FD_SET' function declaration in `select.h`

Tags: c, select, clion

I'm learning unix network programming. I include `#include <sys/select.h>` and call `FD_SET` function. The code can compile successfully when I run `gcc` manually.

The problem is my IDE `Clion` can not recognize `FD_SET`, so it can not help me auto-complete the rest code when I type `FD_`. So I check the `select.h` file, I can not find `FD_SET` declaration in the file.

Here is the source code of `select.h` on my Mac:

```
#ifndef _SYS_SELECT_H_
#define _SYS_SELECT_H_

#include <sys/appleapiopts.h>
#include <sys/cdefs.h>
#include <sys/_types.h>

/*
 * [XSI] The <sys/select.h> header shall define the fd_set type as a structure.
 * The timespec structure shall be defined as described in <time.h>
 * The <sys/select.h> header shall define the timeval structure.
 */
#include <sys/_types/_fd_def.h>
#include <sys/_types/_timespec.h>
#include <sys/_types/_timeval.h>

/*
 * The time_t and suseconds_t types shall be defined as described in
 * <sys/types.h>
 * The sigset_t type shall be defined as described in <signal.h>
 */
#include <sys/_types/_time_t.h>
#include <sys/_types/_suseconds_t.h>
#include <sys/_types/_sigset_t.h>

/*
 * [XSI] FD_CLR, FD_ISSET, FD_SET, FD_ZERO may be declared as a function, or
 *   defined as a macro, or both
 * [XSI] FD_SETSIZE shall be defined as a macro
 */

/*
 * Select uses bit masks of file descriptors in longs.  These macros
 * manipulate such bit fields (the filesystem macros use chars).  The
 * extra protection here is to permit application redefinition above
 * the default size.
 */
#include <sys/_types/_fd_setsize.h>
#include <sys/_types/_fd_set.h>
#include <sys/_types/_fd_clr.h>
#include <sys/_types/_fd_isset.h>
#include <sys/_types/_fd_zero.h>

#if !defined(_POSIX_C_SOURCE) || defined(_DARWIN_C_SOURCE)
#include <sys/_types/_fd_copy.h>
#endif  /* (!_POSIX_C_SOURCE || _DARWIN_C_SOURCE) */


__BEGIN_DECLS

#ifndef  __MWERKS__
int      pselect(int, fd_set * __restrict, fd_set * __restrict,
    fd_set * __restrict, const struct timespec * __restrict,
    const sigset_t * __restrict)
#if defined(_DARWIN_C_SOURCE) || defined(_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT)
__DARWIN_EXTSN_C(pselect)
#else /* !_DARWIN_C_SOURCE && !_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT */
#  if defined(__LP64__) && !__DARWIN_NON_CANCELABLE
__DARWIN_1050(pselect)
#  else /* !__LP64__ || __DARWIN_NON_CANCELABLE */
__DARWIN_ALIAS_C(pselect)
#  endif /* __LP64__ && !__DARWIN_NON_CANCELABLE */
#endif /* _DARWIN_C_SOURCE || _DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT */
;
#endif /* __MWERKS__ */

#include <sys/_select.h>        /* select() prototype */

__END_DECLS


#endif /* !_SYS_SELECT_H_ */
```

So, where can I find `FD_SET` declaration? And how should I configure my `clion` so it can recognize it?

Comment: `FD_SET` is typically implemented as a *macro* (as are the other `FD_*` "functions". And there is no rule that they have to be defined in directly in the advertised header file. As you can see in your copy of `select.h` it include quite a lot of *other* header file, some "private" (as indicated by the `_` prefix), and the macros could be defined in any of them.

Comment: You could also look as [this CLion preprocessor umbrella issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-1088) to see if your problem might be listed. And if not then please create a [mcve] and post an issue yourself.